# Rails - Add custom route constraint for "/admin"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ActiveAdmin on my current Rails application.
In my routes, I would like to create a route constraint so that "/admin" namespace would be accessible just to users that have an attribute admin on true (boolean attribute).

I tried looking into Rails route constraints but I haven't figured out yet how to properly use a defined method to validate/invalidate the constraint.Something like

```
def check_me
  current_user.admin #current_user method from Devise
end
```

to be used

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your ActiveAdmin authentication, check it [here.](https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#authentication)

define your method:

```
def check_me
  current_user.admin?
end
```

then change your configuration:

```
config.current_user_method = :check_me
```